# powershell : pipe get-content to ps1 file with parameters

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script which uses the powershell cmdlet get-content tail and inserts the new lines into the sql server table.  i can't get the syntax to pipe the tail to the sqlinsert.ps1 file that handles the table insert.

i'm looking for help on how to pipe "get-content tail" to a sqlinsert.ps1 file to do a sql database insert statement using the following :

```
$startTime = get-date
Write-Host "\\iisserver\logs\Logs-$("{0:yyyyMMdd}" -f (get-date)).txt"
get-content "\\iisserver\logs\Logs-$("{0:yyyyMMdd}" -f (get-date)).txt" -tail 1 -wait  |  & "sqlinsert.ps1" -stmp $("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff}" -f (get-date)) -method "Error" -msg $_
# %  { "$_ read at $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")" }
```

in the sqlinsert.ps1 :

```
param ([string]$stmp, [string]$method, [string]$msg ) 
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "server='$serverName';database='$databaseName';User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
$Command.Connection = $Connection

$sql = "insert into [tbl_iiserrors] (errstamp, method, msg) values (@stmp , @method, @msg)  "
```

.
.
.

error i get:

> & : The term 'sqlinsert.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At C:\Temp\ob\iislog\tst_tail.ps1:3 char:95
>
> - ... Mdd}" -f (get-date)).txt" -tail 1 -wait  |  & "sqlinsert.ps1" -stmp $ ...
> - ```
>                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sqlinsert.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> Suggestion [3,General]: The command sqlinsert.ps1 was not found, but
> does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load
> commands from the current location by default. If you trust this
> command, instead type: ".\sqlinsert.ps1". See "get-help
> about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

The sqlinsert.ps1 works when i run it from powershell command :
PS c:\temp> .\sqlinsert -stmp 2020-11-20 00:00:00 -method 'eek' -msg 'uh hello'

Comment: The error says that it cannot find the file in the current directory. Try with the full path: `& 'C:\temp\sqlinsert.ps1'`

Comment: after the pipe, i changed it to  .\sqlinsert.ps1 -stmp $("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff}" -f (get-date)) -method "Error" -msg $_   It looks like its running but it doesn't look like its passing through correctly?  i don't see any insertions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind pipeline input to a parameter, you need to decorate it with a `[Parameter]` attribute and specify that it accepts pipeline input, like this:

```
param (
  [string]$stmp,
  [string]$method, 
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [string]$msg
)
```

See the [`about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` help file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) for more details about how to modify the behavior of parameters

Comment: C:\sqlinsert.ps1 : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
+ ...  1 -wait  | .\sqlinsert.ps1 -stmp '2020-11-20 00:00:00' -method 'Erro ...
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (2020-11-20 16:2...s 200 text/html:PSObject) [sqlinsert.ps1], Parameter
   BindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,sqlinsert.ps1

Answer (score 0):

- By design, for security reasons, PowerShell requires you to signal the intent to execute a script located in the current directory explicitly, using a *path* - `.\sqlinsert.ps1` - rather than a *mere file name* - `sqlinsert.ps1`; that is what the suggestion following the error message is trying to tell you.

  - Note that you only need `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), if the script path is quoted and/or contains variable references - and `.\sqlinsert.ps1` doesn't require quoting.
- You can only use the automatic `$_` variable, which represents the current input object from the pipeline inside a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`), such as one passed to the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet, which invokes that block for each object received via the pipeline.
- Re the content of your script: Inside [expandable strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (`"..."`), you cannot use `@` to refer to variables to be expanded (interpolated); use regular, `$`-prefixed variable references or `$(...)`, the subexpression operator to embed expressions; also, it looks like you're inserting *string* values into the SQL table, so you'll have to enclose the expanded variable values in embedded `'...'`

```
$startTime = get-date
Get-Content "\\iisserver\logs\Logs-$("{0:yyyyMMdd}" -f (get-date)).txt" -Tail 1 -Wait |  
 ForEach-Object {
   .\sqlinsert.ps1 -stmp ("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff}" -f (get-date)) -method "Error" -msg $_
 }
```

The alternative to using a `ForEach-Object` call is to modify your script to *directly* receive its `-msg` argument from the pipeline, as shown in [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64937560/45375), in which case you must *omit* the `-msg $_` argument from your script call:

```
Get-Content ... |
  .\sqlinsert.ps1 -stmp ("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff}" -f (get-date)) -method "Error"
```